# Cocoa without XCode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, gcc, ide

I would like to develop Mac applications, but don't want to use XCode. I have many reasons...

1. It's VERY slow...
2. It's complicated...
3. The Interface Builder seems like cheating and is not as satisfying. (I know, old school)
4. The whole developer tools set takes a lot of space and takes a long time to download (meanwhile slowing the rest of my computer down)

I know it's possible because I have seen some scripts compiled with gcc. Are there any tutorials? Are there any tips? I know how to run it, but I just need help learning how to use it without XCode making code for me. Is this a good plan, or is this just destined for failure?

Comment: Would you consider using another IDE, like AppCode (http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)?

Comment: If number 3 is really bothering you then you could always edit the storyboard source (this makes it xml editing).  Also, you should really use clang/llvm rather than gcc or at least LLVM/GCC since apple has discontinued support of pure GCC.

Comment: AppCode is brilliant, and highly recommended. But you still need Xcode in many cases.

Comment: Note that IB is not cheating. IB is a core part of Mac development. It's like saying that Objective-C is cheating rather than writing in Assembler. Regarding #4, you cannot avoid installing Xcode, even if you don't run it. All the other tools will start with the instructions "install Xcode, then...."

Comment: I don't think you understand how InterfaceBuilder works. Basically it creates a serialized object graph. If you code this by hand, you are not doing anything different (the main difference is that you create the object graph on the fly, while otherwise it is restored from your xib/nib file).

Comment: In addition I assume you don't want to sell your application on the appstore.

Comment: The editor changed the whole meaning of my question. I don't want to learn how to use XCode or how to stop XCode from doing things. I appreciate the attempt to help, but please keep my original meaning when you edit.

Comment: What editor? The only thing [Parag changed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9332667/revisions) was the tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I didn't say that I want to learn how to use XCode. I'll check, but if I did, sorry.

Comment: So this question was deemed "not constructive" because it disses Apple's tool chain?  So, if you're not politically correct enough, you can't get the answers you're looking for?

Comment: Ok, the OP has a bit of a pissy attitude.  I don't want to step on their toes, so rather than edit this, I'll re-ask the question, disguised as well as I can make it as a different question, and try to lose the attitude.

Comment: @Shavais Frankly, I'm quite embarrassed at my actions/attitude! Haha, feel free as that would be much healthier for the community

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc//).

> AppCode is an IDE for Objective-C developers building native Cocoa
>   apps for MacOS X or iOS who strive for higher coding productivity and
>   better code quality.

[EditRocket](http://www.editrocket.com/features/objective-c_editor.html).

> EditRocket can compile and execute Objective-C programs. EditRocket
>   uses the gcc compiler to compile Objective-C programs

[GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/).

> GNUstep provides a robust implementation of the AppKit and Foundation
>   libraries as well as the development tools available on Cocoa,
>   including Gorm (the InterfaceBuilder) and ProjectCenter
>   (ProjectBuilder/Xcode).

[THE COCOTRON](http://www.cocotron.org/Info)

> The Cocotron is an open source project which aims to implement a
>   cross-platform Objective-C API similar to that described by Apple
>   Inc.'s Cocoa documentation. This includes the AppKit, Foundation,
>   Objective-C runtime and support APIs such as CoreGraphics and
>   CoreFoundation

.
Take a look at [build and run a Cocoa Mac application on the command-line](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html) post.
[alternatives to XCode for iPhone development? (OR: how to make XCode suck less?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803366/alternatives-to-xcode-for-iphone-development-or-how-to-make-xcode-suck-less).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what code you think Xcode is generating for you, but if you want to use another IDE then you're free to. Xcode includes all the standard UNIXy command line tools (though, as of 4.3 you have explicitly to make them available by launching Xcode exactly once and ticking a box in the settings), so you'd use standard GCC methods.

Besides the observation given e.g. [here](http://www.thoughtstuff.com/rme/weblog/?p=8) that you'll want to link against the Foundation framework, there's really not much to say.

For the record, the interface designer doesn't generate any code and is therefore no more 'cheating' than using a paint package to draw your graphics.

Answer (score 5):

> or is this just destined for failure?

Probably. Apple is making OS X and iOS development very tightly tied to the use of Xcode, particularly if you are intending to submit apps to either store. You'll spend a lot of time working out how to do things the non-Xcode way.

Looking at your points in turn:

1. More than using x many different tools to achieve the same thing?
2. See 1.
3. You don't have to use interface builder if you don't want to, but your given reason ("cheating") is nonsensical.
4. Most of that is documentation, which you will need anyway. It is quite nicely integrated into the editor if you use Xcode.

Comment: Agreed that you don't have to use IB if you don't want to... but you should learn it anyway. Knowing when it is appropriate and when it is not is a key part of development. As @Tommy notes, IB does not generate any code. It generates data.

Answer (score 1):

you are going to waste more time massaging your custom environment than you would waste by just drinking the kool-aid.

It is reasonable to use some other text editor and use xcode for editing your build environment, then you would be free to execute builds from the command line.........

Comment: ha, I didn't realize this was edited by the great @marksuman :)

Comment: Haha. Glad to be of service! Although this change says nothing about my coding abilities.