# Is there a Command Line alternative to Xcode & Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm using XCode to develop an App for Mac OS X. Xcode is heavy on my Mac Resources and it makes the machine pretty sluggish when i work on it for some long time(more than 8 hours). I used to work in C++ with the Command Line & Makefile and it was pretty enough and good for me. Is it Possible that i can Develop apps for Mac, which has some UI(NSStatusItem) fully through Command Line or mostly command Line ?

I explored through some Makefiles for Objective C, but i don't know how to bind the UI actions to the Code. I doubt if it's really possible though Command Line.

Comment: There's the `xcodebuild` command: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html — you can edit your code say in MacVim and build from the command line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa without XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332667/cocoa-without-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried Searching for Command Line alternative for Xcode, but there seems to be None. The Only Choice is Xcode for developing Mac Apps.

Answer (score 1):

I found out this. Maybe it'll help you :)

http://atastypixel.com/blog/objective-c-cocoa-on-the-command-line/

Comment: It's useful, for testing some code snippets. I'm looking for a CommandLine alternative to Xcode

Comment: Yeah I know, I just thought it could be useful to you. Otherwise, you could write the code in some text editor, save it as .m and .h files and compile it through terminal and gcc.

Comment: This could be helpful - http://www.w3style.co.uk/compiling-objective-c-without-xcode-in-os-x

Comment: Dominik,  i'm looking for a Complete Command Line alternative to Xcode, thanks anyway for your links.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately there is nothing like that :(

Comment: hmm, that's Sad. Ok, i'll carry on With the XCode itself.